# WebAssembly: Where is the heap stored? Is it possible to access it via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, webassembly

Is it possible to access the heap of the calling WASM instance within an imported Javascript function?

Comment: What, just...anywhere in the heap, arbitrarily? Why would you want to do that? (I sure hope it's not possible...) Please clarify exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: I want to make a WASM process ortogonal persistent, not only between function calls, but also within them, if they run out of resources (which is accounted for by another imported function which is injected into the source before instantiation).

Comment: Then shouldn't the question be "How do I make the WASM instance's heap orthogonally persistent?" perhaps adding "from JavaScript" if doing it externally like that is a requirement?

Comment: The question is general and specific enough that it would answer my problem. Not sure if many people understand what orthogonal persistence is, so I'll leave it at that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebAssembly does not (yet) have a heap. It only has linear memory, which you can simply export and then access from JavaScript as a WebAssembly.Memory instance.